# Updating ac value for Qtimer

Tags: qt, user-interface, adc

I am using qt tool for mini2440.
I make a gui for i2c adc having starti2c and stopi2c.
All things are working well: it reads value of signal when starti2c button press, but I want this value to be updated. I know that Qtimer can be used, but how can I do it?
Here is the code:

---

```
# include <termio.h>
# include <time.h>
# include <string.h>
# include <sys/time.h>

HelloForm::HelloForm(QWidget* parent, const char* name, WFlags fl):

HelloBaseForm(parent, name, fl)

{

connect(PushButton1,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(starti2c()));
connect(PushButton2,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(stopi2c()));

}

HelloForm::~HelloForm()  

{

}

//*********************Code for getting i2c**************************// 
  char HelloForm::geti2c()
{

  char buf[100];                              
  char buff[100];     
  char valuee;

  int m1;   

  char con_buff[10];

  int fd=open("/dev/i2c/0",O_RDWR);

  if (fd<0)
  {

   Message->setText(" NOT ABLE TO OPEN THE DRIVER ");

   }

   else

  {

  Message->setText(" I2C IS WORKING ");

}

    int  io,wbyte,rbyte,i;

   //********i2cdetect and read************

   buf[0]=0x48;    

  buf[1]=0x00;   

  buf[2]=0x91;  

  io=ioctl(fd,I2C_SLAVE,0x48); 

  if(io<0)

{

Message->setText(" ");

 Message->setText("error ioctl");

 }

 else

 {

 wbyte=write(fd,buf,3); 
                   // write all three control word to arm 
 usleep(1*1000);

 }

 if(wbyte!=3)

{
Message->setText("error write");

Message->setText(QString::number(wbyte));

rbyte=read(fd,buff,10);    

//ADC->setText(buff);

sscanf(buff,"%c",&valuee);             

m1=int(valuee);     

return(m1);

}


void HelloForm::starti2c()

{


while(1)

{   

float adc_val=0;

adc_val=geti2c();

adc_val=(adc_val*5)/255.00;

usleep(1*1000);   

ADC->setText(QString::number(adc_val));   
  }
  }

//***********stop********//
void HelloForm::stopi2c()
{                        

   ADC->setText(" ");
Message->setText("Stopped");
}
```

---

Comment: can anyone please tell me ...its urgent i am using trolltech qt 2.2.0

Comment: I do not really understand a question. But `QTimer` has its `timeout` signal used for updates. Also Qt 2.2? This is **15** years old. You should probably think about using a newer version

Comment: `i want this value to be update` => which one ? @Bowdzone he may refers to Qt Creator 2.2, which is a bit younger

Comment: sir i want update the values which is adc value starti2c() function in every 2 seconds... i tried on google but i didn't understand how can i do it in my this programme...i am new in qt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this will get you started - it creates a timer which times out every 1000 milli seconds.  The timer's timeout signal is connected to the same slot that your PushButton1 is connected to - starti2c.

```
QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(starti2c()));
timer->start(1000);
```

That code should be placed below where you have your 2 connection statements.

Comment: You would need to #include <QTimer>

Comment: HelloForm::HelloForm( QWidget* parent, const char* name, WFlags fl):
    HelloBaseForm(parent, name, fl)
    {
    connect(PushButton1,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(starti2c()));
    connect(PushButton2,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(stopi2c()));
    QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(starti2c()));
    timer->start(1000);
    }

Comment: hello.cpp:6:18: error: QTimer: No such file or directory
hello.cpp: In constructor 'HelloForm::HelloForm(QWidget*, const char*, uint)':
hello.cpp:47: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct QTimer'
/opt/FriendlyARM/mini2440/arm-qtopia/qtopia-2.2.0-FriendlyARM/qt2/include/qwindowdefs.h:81: error: forward declaration of 'struct QTimer'
hello.cpp:48: error: no matching function for call to 'HelloForm::connect(QTimer*&, const char [11], HelloForm* const, const char [12])'

Comment: /opt/FriendlyARM/mini2440/arm-qtopia/qtopia-2.2.0-FriendlyARM/qt2/include/qobject.h:208: note:                 bool QObject::connect(const QObject*, const char*, const char*) const
hello.cpp:49: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct QTimer'
/opt/FriendlyARM/mini2440/arm-qtopia/qtopia-2.2.0-FriendlyARM/qt2/include/qwindowdefs.h:81: error: forward declaration of 'struct QTimer'
hello.cpp: In member function 'char HelloForm::geti2c()':
hello.cpp:74: warning: unused variable 'i'
make: *** [.obj/release-shared/hello.o] Error 1

Comment: yes!!! it works.....these errors are with using QTimer.h it correct it as qtimer....now by pushing button it update the value......but when press stop it stops and starts again....

Comment: I'm glad you got it going.  What you could do is have button1 start the timer and button2 stop it.

Comment: sir, i need two switch to start adc with regular update and stop it when i need...

Comment: i need to update adc value when i press start button in my gui but by entering the app it starts auto matically....and other one is i need to stop it when i want.....

Comment: I think you need to move the timer->start(1000) line from the constructor and put it into the button click handler

Comment: in your stop button handler you should put timer->sop();

Comment: You'll need to declare the timer in you header (.h) file in order to give it scope in the button handlers.

Comment: void HelloForm::starti2c()

          {


          timer->start(1000);

          {   

          float adc_val=0;

          adc_val=geti2c();

          adc_val=(adc_val*5)/255.00;

          usleep(1*1000);   

         ADC->setText(QString::number(adc_val));   
         }
         }

Comment: [/code]                   void HelloForm::starti2c()

                     {


                 timer->start(1000);

          {   

          float adc_val=0;

          adc_val=geti2c();

          adc_val=(adc_val*5)/255.00;

          usleep(1*1000);   

         ADC->setText(QString::number(adc_val));   
         }
         }[code/]

Comment: plzz give any solution so that i can make a step ahead.

Comment: Where are you at?  What have you got working so far?

Comment: sir i am actually very new in qt as well as friendly arm and gui....i read the qt on qt website but i don't know how to use such things in my programme ..that's why i am asking to you.